# dymamic Schemas and nested Maps in Avro

Tags: avro

I'm new to Avro, and am trying to write some code to serialize some nested objects.

The structure of the objects looks like this:

```
class Parcel  {
    String recipe;
    Map<Integer, PluginDump> dumps;
}

class PluginDump  {
   byte[] state;
   Map<String, Param> params;
}


class Param {
   Type type;  //can be e.g. StringType, BooleanType, etc
   Object value;
}
```

So I can't use a static avro schema - each PluginDump will have a different schema depending on the types within it.

I have written some code which can generate a Schema based on an individual PluginDump.

So when serializing a Parcel, how do I 'put' each PluginDump entry?

Here is my code:

```
Schema parcelSchema = AvroHelper.getSchema(p);
GenericRecord parcelRecord = new GenericData.Record(parcelSchema);
parcelRecord.put("recipe", p.getRecipe().toJson());
for (Map.Entry<Integer, PluginDump> entry : p.getDumps().entrySet()) {
        PluginDump dump = entry.getValue();
        Integer uid = entry.getKey();
        Schema dumpSchema = AvroHelper.getSchema(dump);//will be different for each PluginDump
        parcelRecord.put(????
```

Any ideas?

I have a feeling my approach is wrong, but I can't find any examples in the documentation of dynamic schema generation or nested maps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1** When you get `GenericRecord parcelRecord = new GenericData.Record(parcelSchema);` you have two fields in your record: recipe and dumps, so you can't iterate through the dumps, you must put prepared map with dumps in the second field of record, just like you did it for recipe: `parcelRecord.put("dumps", dumps);`. But in this case, you'll get ClassCastException, because PluginDump cannot be cast to org.apache.avro.generic.IndexedRecord, so you need to put in parcelRecord a Map of GenericRecords. Also you need this for `Map<String, Param> params`, cause Param cannot be cast to IndexedRecord too.

**2** Then, I think that its better to use Lists instead of Maps, cause avro not very good enough to work with Maps with different types of keys and values.

**3** About the Param class: if you will use auto-generated schema, Param class will be presented like this.

```
"type": "record",
"name": "Param",
"fields": [
    {
        "name": "type",
        "type": {
            "type": "record",
            "name": "Type",
            "namespace": "java.lang.reflect",
            "fields": []
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "value",
        "type": {
            "type": "record",
            "name": "Object",
            "namespace": "java.lang",
            "fields": []
        }
    }
]
```

As far as avro uses java.lang.reflect, you will lose type field after deserialization, avro will not know what type it was.

If you want to generate avro-schema manually for each Param, considering its type, you can do something like this (**I used ClassUtils.getClass from apache commons-lang3, cause standart Class.forName method doesn't always work properly**):

```
public Schema getParamSchema() throws ClassNotFoundException {
        List<Schema.Field> fields = new ArrayList<>();

        fields.add(new Schema.Field("key", Schema.create(Schema.Type.STRING), "Doc: key field", (Object) null));
        Schema.Field f = new Schema.Field("type", ReflectData.get().getSchema(ClassUtils.getClass(((Class) this.type).getName())), "Doc: type field", (Object) null);
        f.addProp("java-class", ((Class) this.type).getName());
        fields.add(f);
        fields.add(new Schema.Field("value", ReflectData.get().getSchema(value.getClass()), "Doc: value field", (Object) null));

        return Schema.createRecord(((Class) this.type).getName() + "Param", "Doc: param record", this.getClass().getPackage().getName(), false, fields);
    }
```

But in this case, avro will throw ClassCastException, because it can't cast Class to Boolean, Integer etc. I always had a lot of problems working with avro and java Types and Classes.

So the best advice i think will be to change you model (Parcel, PluginDump and Param i mean) to have less problems with avro. For example you can store type name like a string, and get a Type with reflection after deserializing.